# prevent the file from going to download folder

Tags: html, flask

Upload button  gives a copy of uploaded file in the desired location But i could get the file in downloads directory as well.

i am trying to upload a file into a desired location the file path has some functionality to do which is working fine but i am getting a box asking to save file or cancel which upon clicking the save button stores the file in download folder which i don't want

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, \
    send_from_directory
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = '/home/personal/mytweets'
app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS'] = set(['txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])


def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1] in app.config['ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS']


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    # Get the name of the uploaded file
    file = request.files['file']
    # Check if the file is one of the allowed types/extensions
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        # Make the filename safe, remove unsupported chars
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename))


@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int("80"), debug=True)
```

-------Index.html------------------

```
enter code here
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
   <body>
     <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
       <h3 class="text-muted">Upload a Test File</h3>
  </div>

  <div>

  <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
  </html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please take care of your code format.

Comment: i am trying to upload a file into a desired location the file path has some functionality to do which is working fine but i am getting a box asking to save file or cancel which upon clicking the save button stores the file in download folder which i dont want ... @utkbansal

Comment: Please format your code firstly.

Comment: @utkbansal i am sorry im new to this part please dont mind

Comment: could you add the code in the index.html file?

Comment: @utkbansal i have added it please help me out  :)

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood your question, but why do you force-download the file with `send_from_directory` if you do not want to download the file?

Comment: yea @Dauros i have removed it i could get the output